# os.path.join fails with "TypeError: object of type 'LocalPath' has no len()"

Tags: python, pytest, os.path

This error appeared when trying to use the 'tmpdir' in a pytest test.

> TypeError: object of type 'LocalPath' has no len()

Answer (score 23, accepted):

'tmpdir' is of type `<class 'py._path.local.LocalPath'>`, just wrap 'tmpdir' in a string when passing to `os.path.join`

example:

`os.path.join(str(tmpdir), 'my_test_file.txt')`

Comment: Or even: `str(tmpdir / 'my_test_file.txt')`

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can directly access the string form of LocalPath as an attribute.

```py
  os.path.join(tmpdir.strpath, 'my_test_file.txt')
```

I used to think that using the attribute access meant that you were not casting the object to a string thus being more efficient but I think I am wrong in that assumption however, I like this style a bit better it is easier to write IMHO